# How can I change the output serialization for text/html in WCF 4 Automatic Format Selection?

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.0

WCF has implemented mime type serialization selection, so that accept headers of the request affect how the response is serialized.  This is a wonderful change and it makes writing my REST endpoints much simpler.

However.

When using "automaticFormatSelectionEnabled=true", one of the formats automatically handled is "text/html", and its result is to return all the field data from the response object concatenated with no separator. This isn't particularly useful, especially for testing using a web browser.

Here's the accept header from Firefox:

`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8`

What I'd like to to have a more meaningful response from these requests headers.  This could be accomplished, in order of preference:

1. Ignore text/html and application/xhtml+xml in the accept header so application/xml is returned
2. Have text/html use the same serializer as application/XML and return the results as text/html
3. Provide a custom serializer for text/html so I could serialize the response object to html in whatever format I choose; it would still return as text/html

Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

MediaTypeProcessors will do the job for you - you can get the bits from the [WCF CodePlex site](http://wcf.codeplex.com/).  Here is an example of using them to return your desired format (xml, json, html, etc.): [WCF Media Type Processors](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/11/17/combine-wcf-mediatypeprocessors-with-a-custom-razor-host.aspx)